# Interpreting and formatting user input

Tags: c#, string

I'm designing a command line interpreter for my software and need to be able to format user input. Currently I have a system which basically splits everything by spaces, the problem is that I need to not split anything inside double quotes.

As you can probably tell, my current implementation won't handle quoted paths very well.

This is my current interpreting and formatting logic (contained in a non static method which gets called when the user presses enter, in case anyone was wondering):

```
 var command = ConsoleInput.Text;
                ConsoleInput.Text = String.Empty;

                string command_main = command.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).First();
                string[] synatx = command.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Skip(1).ToArray();

                if (lCommands.ContainsKey(command_main))
                {
                    Action<string[]> commandfunction;
                    lCommands.TryGetValue(command_main, out commandfunction);
                    commandfunction(synatx);
                }
                else
                    ConsoleOut($"Invalid Command - {command_main} {string.Join(" ", synatx)}");
```

I need quoted paths to be taken in as a single argument, instead of being split by spacing. 
for example, (disclaimer: this is just an example and not actual code)

**this is what I don't want:** *with an input of:  "this is a test" and some more text* it turns out to be something like this: syntax[0] = "this syntax[1] = is, and so on.

**The expected outcome would be (what I want to happen):** syntax[0] = "this is a test" syntax[1] = and syntax[2] = some, and so on.

I'm stuck here, anyone have a solution? Thank you.

Comment: oh by the way, here's my concept code for getting the text from within double quotes
`var result = from Match match in Regex.Matches(line, "\"([^\"]*)\"") 
             select match.ToString();`

Comment: Have you considered using existing libraries rather than rolling this yourself?

Comment: .net has a delimited parser.  It's in the vb namespace..

Comment: What does this have to do with `[wpf]` and why did you tag it with `[arrays]`. If you are going to do it by hand, go all the way. Write a tiny state machine that walks through the input looking for spaces and quotes and whatever else you want. It's reasonably easy to write, and very easy to write tests for

Comment: @mjwills I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @HeribertoLugo Sorry but that's not much of an option for me.

Comment: @Flydog57 Fixed that, thought it would be relevant because I'm making all this in a wpf application, and I'm using arrays for some of it.

Comment: Why isn't using the Microsoft supplied solution that @heribertolugo suggests an option? Don't be scared of the VB namespace.  It will be in your target system's GAC like any other Microsoft assembly.  You don't need any VB stuff, it's callable from C#

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution.  It's a hacked together state machine that handles quoted strings that may contain spaces.  It throws away extraneous whitespace between arguments, and considers a doubled up double-quote as if it were a single double-quote (but without any special meaning; as if it were any other character).

```
 public IEnumerable<string> ParseLine(string toParse)
 {
     var result = new List<string>();
     bool inQuotedString = false;
     bool parsingDoubleQuote = false;
     bool inWhiteSpace = false;
     int length = toParse.Length;
     var argBuffer = new StringBuilder();

     for (var index = 0; index < length; ++index)
     {
         //if looking ahead for a double quote succeeded, just add the quote to the current arguemnt
         if (parsingDoubleQuote)
         {
             parsingDoubleQuote = false;
             argBuffer.Append('"');
             //and we are done with this character, so...
             continue;  //done with this character, time to just loop again
         }

         if (toParse[index] == '"')
         {
             inWhiteSpace = false;
             //look ahead one character to see if there's a double quote
             if (index < length - 1 && toParse[index + 1] == '"')
             {
                 parsingDoubleQuote = true;
                 continue;      //done with this character, time to just loop again
             }

             if (!inQuotedString)
             {
                 inQuotedString = true;
                 continue; //done with this character, time to just loop again
             }
             else
             {
                 //it's not a double quote, and we are in quotes string, so
                 inQuotedString = false;
                 //we don't add the buffer to the output args until a space or the end, so
                 continue;      //done with this character, time to just loop again
             }
         }
         //if we are here, there's no quote, so...
         if (toParse[index] == ' ' || toParse[index] == '\t')
         {
             if (inQuotedString)
             {
                 argBuffer.Append(toParse[index]);
                 continue;    //done with this character, time to just loop again
             }
             if (inWhiteSpace)
             {
                 //nothing to do
                 continue;     //out of the for loop
             }
             else
             {
                 inWhiteSpace = true;
                 if (argBuffer.Length > 0)
                 {
                     result.Add(argBuffer.ToString());
                     argBuffer.Clear();
                     continue;       //done with this character, time to just loop again
                 }
             }
         }
         else
         {
             inWhiteSpace = false;
             //no quote, no space, so...
             argBuffer.Append(toParse[index]);
             continue;     //done with this character, time to just loop again
         }
     }   //end of for loop
     if (argBuffer.Length > 0)
     {
         result.Add(argBuffer.ToString());
     }
     return result;
 }
```

I've given it cursory testing - you'll want to test it harder